# How to know if Ionic split pane is opened or closed?

Tags: ionic-framework, splitpane

I'm trying to adjust some CSS properties depending on the state of the split pane, I mean, if it is opened or closed. I can detect when its state changes using `ionChange` event on the view, but I can't know if it was opened or closed. Is there a way to do this?

Split Pane documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/split-pane/SplitPane/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for the same behavior and found [this](https://github.com/boradakash/ionic-split-pane-demo#3-events). Here's an example:

```
<ion-split-pane (ionChange)="onSplitPaneChange($event)">
    ...
</ion-split-pane>
```

And in your component:

```
onSplitPaneChange(e) {
    if (e._visible) {
        // desktop
    } else {
        // mobile
    }
}
```

This was tested for **Ionic 3**.

According to [Redwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5790850/redwolf),  on **Ionic 4** you'll have to read `e.detail.visible` instead of `e._visible` (I didn't try it myself yet - comment if you did). The rest may remain and works the same way though.

Comment: On Ionic 4 you can use (ionSplitPaneVisible)="function($event)"

Comment: @Notmfb that's true and nice!